# Easy way to invert the polarity of array elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby, I have an array:

```
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
```

I want to get:

```
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
```

I'm sure Ruby has an easy one-line solution, but it escapes me right now.

Comment: I know array.collect { |x| x*-1 } works but I was wondering if there is a one word method that does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1].map {|e| -e}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Also:

```
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1].map &:-@
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1].map(&-1.method(:*))
```

To explain how it works:

```
-1.method(:*)
```

is me saying to the `-1` object "Can you please return to me a method object that represents you being multiplied by a variable?" and

```
map(&...)
```

is me saying "rather than giving you a literal block, I'm going to give you something prefixed with an ampersand that acts like a block".

The RDoc documentation for `method` can be seen [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method).